# Nodejs ajax sync calls not working from 2024 january (Chrome)

Tags: node.js, ajax, google-chrome, asynchronous

Premise: I know that "sync" is evil and that nobody should use it. I don't expect answers like "don't use sync" or "rewrite it async". I already know! Thanks.

I have a software that, shortly, does this:

1. ejs web page calls ajax (async: false)
2. node.js server (express) gets the POST and retrieves a number from database
3. server sends back data
4. client gets the data and (in the "done" or "success" callback of ajax) puts it in a variable
5. client draws and shows a form with the variable value in a field (is sync, so the field is filled)

Since 12th of january all worked fine.
Then the form started to be shown without the number in the field (and without any console error in browser).

It seems that not all users have the problem! Some Windows 10 + Chrome 120 have the issue, I have the same configuration and I don't have any issue. So it becomes very hard to "test" and debug since I have no way to create the issue on my browser.

It seems not to be dependent by Chrome Version (I have tried with 90, 106, 117, 120).
Users that have the problem with Chrome, if using Edge browser, have the old "correct" behaviour.
Users on Apple (Safari) don't have the problem.

No difference if using JQuery ($.ajax) or "plain" javascript.

I have put some console.log into the client code. In particular:

- one in the "done" or "success" function of the ajax call (named "ONE" - into step 4 above)
- one after the whole ajax call (named "TWO" - as a step 4.5)

Where all is ok, the system behave as sync and in the browser Console I see

1. ONE with value
2. TWO with value

Where I get the error I receive

1. TWO without value!
2. ONE with value

Shortly, it seems that the sync call is suddenly handled as async...

Does anyone have an idea of why from an X day the same software on the same browser changed its behaviour and not for all users?

Thanks

Comment: Chrome and other browsers are step by step removing scenarios where you can use synchronous XHR. See for example the case of [Synchronous XMLHTTPRequest() in Page Dismissal](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912). You clearly indicate that you know synchronous XHR is deprecated, so what do you want to hear!? Best practice? You already know what it is.

Comment: @trincot I want to hear "why from an X day the same software on the same browser changed its behaviour and not for all users?" I mean, all have the same software releases, some work some don't. Why?